# Two inline Bootstrap datepickers not fitting bootstrap grid column and panel

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am a newbie when it comes to frontend. I have been working on a little single page angularjs app and I came across an issue. On my page, I need two inline datepickers. I chose angular-ui-bootstrap datepickers. They render in an odd way veiling each other:

[veiling datepickers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8bvN.jpg)

Here's part of my HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4>Date range</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <div style="display: inline-block;">
                            <uib-datepicker ng-model="dateFrom" starting-day="1" max-date="dateTo" show-weeks="false"></uib-datepicker>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label>Date from {{dateFrom | date: "dd/MM/yyyy"}}</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-5 ">
                        <div style="display: inline-block;">
                            <uib-datepicker ng-model="dateTo" starting-day="1" min-date="dateFrom" show-weeks="false"></uib-datepicker>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label>Date to {{dateTo | date: "dd/MM/yyyy"}}</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <label> Additional Info</label>
</div>
```

Do you have any idea how to make them fit the panel normally without this veiling? 

 Before I put datepickers into panel div, the display issue was the same. They were tighten together and not fitting the grid column.

Each help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

As `<uib-datepicker>` has a fixed size and cannot be resized according to grid width, you can customize the size of the small buttons (days).
See in the snippet below the `.custom-size .btn-sm` CSS class:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

});
```

```css
.custom-size .btn-sm {
padding: 4px 8px;
font-size: 11px;
line-height: 1.5;
border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS UI Bootstrap</title>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.8"></script>
  <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.js"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">

  <div class="container-fluid">
<h2>AngularJS: UI Bootstrap datepicker</h2>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4>Date range</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div style="display: inline-block;">
              <uib-datepicker ng-model="dateFrom" starting-day="1" max-date="dateTo" show-weeks="false" class="custom-size"></uib-datepicker>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label>Date from {{dateFrom | date: "dd/MM/yyyy"}}</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div style="display: inline-block;">
              <uib-datepicker ng-model="dateTo" starting-day="1" min-date="dateFrom" show-weeks="false" class="custom-size"></uib-datepicker>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label>Date to {{dateTo | date: "dd/MM/yyyy"}}</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label> Additional Info</label>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi, this is not a good solution for my app since the panel has to have col width equal to 6 due to upper panels' size. Changing datepickers panel's width causes the UI to look sloppy. What is more when I used your solution I had to change the datepickers col size to 8 to make sure they don't veil each other. Cannot let myself for this without redesigning whole UI, which is not possible now.

Comment: @cAMPy: I edited my answer modifying original size of datepicker mini buttons. Check if it's ok for you.